# How to assign a certain number in an np.array a color in python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matplotlib, matrix

I have a huge array, 
I want to find all the 3s in the array and make them a certain color.

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\605760\Desktop\path rec\matrix1.csv',header=None)
path = zip(*np.where(df==3))
```

and then something where if a number == 3 find the coordinates and mark it green on the map Im returning

Im doing an astar algorithm based off an ROS LiDAR image and I'm plotting the path the robot took as well.
here is the graph

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,15))

##ax.imshow(grid, cmap=plt.cm.Dark2)
ax.imshow(df, cmap = 'gray_r')
ax.scatter(start[1],start[0], marker = "*", color = "yellow", s = 200)
ax.scatter(goal[1],goal[0], marker = "*", color = "red", s = 200)

ax.plot(y_coords,x_coords, color = "black")

##plt.show()
plt.savefig('/Users/605760/Desktop/path rec/newfig1.png')
```

I know its probably simple but I am having trouble incorporation a solution with my other code

Comment: can you add more code including what you are returning

Comment: so you want to plot all points with a y-value of 3 with a specific color, correct?

Comment: yes that's what im trying to do!

Comment: easiest thing to do is just to filter your data (call it `df_filter`) and then plot `df_filter` using `color = green`, that's a very silly trick that's quite common. Your example is quite criptic so it's hard to provide a specific answer

Comment: can I do that on top of the plot im already making? I have a path that im plotting with walls and obstacles

Comment: yes, you can plot over the same plot (you're already plotting over the same axis 4 times)

Comment: Could you create a [mcve], i.e. a runnable code with some toy data that would look like the real case?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to covert class map to label color map like having 2d array for marking each pixel with value like 1 and you want change it to (0,255,0) Green color?

you can use this code to do so.

```
mapping = np.array([[0,0,0],[0,255,0]]) # red for 0 , green for 1, blue for 2 like so on you can add more.
def form_colormap(label, mapping):
    h,w = label.shape
    color_label = np.zeros((h,w,3),dtype=np.uint8)    
    color_label = mapping[prediction]
    color_label = color_label.astype(np.uint8)
    return color_label
```

label should be 2D numpy array. you can check whether it is valid for different shape or not.

as per you said you have different numbers like

```
test = np.array([[2,3,4,0,2,8],
            [5,3,4,6,1,7]])
# make mask array and change it to 0's and 1's 0 represent Non 3's and 1 represent 3's by
mask = test == 3
mask = mask*1

color_label = form_colormap(mask,mapping)
```

later you can display this image py plt.imshow(color_label)
Hope this will help you

Comment: I have an array with 1000s of numbers, mostly 0s and 1s, and then 3s I want to just find the 3s and label them as a color on a plot im displaying